# Android, EspressoTesting with Multiple Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-espresso

I want to access multiple Activity in my Instrumental testing.
e.g Login -> Search-> Listing-> Detail Activity

I have achieved till 'Listing activity' but i want to go for Listing Activity Element[1]'s Detail page.

**Below is my code for**

```
    @RunWith(AndroidJUnit4.class)
     public class ContactSearchScreeenTest  extends  ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<ContactSearchScreen> {

     public ContactSearchScreeenTest() {
        super(ContactSearchScreen.class);
    }

    @Rule
    public ActivityTestRule<ContactSearchScreen> mActivityRule =
            new ActivityTestRule<>(ContactSearchScreen.class);

    @Override
    protected void setUp() throws Exception {
        super.setUp();
    }

    @Test
    public void sendToSearchResultActivity()
    {

        onView(withId(R.id.etSearchName))
                      .perform(typeText("ssasa"), pressKey(KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH));


       GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) mActivityRule.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
        globalVariable.setSearchStr("ssasa");

        mActivityRule.getActivity().callForNextSearchActivity();

    }

}
```

**Additional Functional**

```
    @Override
    public void callForNextSearchActivity() {
     Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(),  SearchResultsActivity.class);
    final GlobalClass globalVariable = (GlobalClass) getApplicationContext();
    globalVariable.setSearchStr(getSearchStringFromSearchEditText());
    startActivity(intent);
    overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);

}
```

Is it possible to have multi activity layer in Espresso testing?
If Yes .. How?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible. In one of the samples they have demoed this.

https://code.google.com/p/android-test-kit/source/browse/testapp_test/src/main/java/com/google/android/apps/common/testing/ui/testapp/BasicTest.java#52][1]

```
public void testTypingAndPressBack() {
// Close soft keyboard after type to avoid issues on devices with soft keyboard.
onView(withId(R.id.sendtext_simple))
    .perform(typeText("Have a cup of Espresso."), closeSoftKeyboard());

onView(withId(R.id.send_simple))
    .perform(click());

// Clicking launches a new activity that shows the text entered above. You don't need to do
// anything special to handle the activity transitions. Espresso takes care of waiting for the
// new activity to be resumed and its view hierarchy to be laid out.
onView(withId(R.id.display_data))
    .check(matches(withText(("Have a cup of Espresso."))));

// Going back to the previous activity - lets make sure our text was perserved.
pressBack();

onView(withId(R.id.sendtext_simple))
    .check(matches(withText(containsString("Espresso"))));
}
```

Read the inline comment.